# Block sharing for a single document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, sharing

In most cases, the ability to share documents is great, but in some cases, we'll need to prevent the users from sharing documents as it is messing up the permissions on that library.

I am aware of the option to block sharing on the site collection level, but in this, I just need it on library level. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Online still not provide option to disable Sharing for a single library, here is the same UserVoice for this:

[Provide an option to disable the "Share" button](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/14343132-provide-an-option-to-disable-the-share-button)

One workaround come up is to use some Jquery code to hide the sharing menu if you are using SharePoint Online classic page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
myVar = setInterval(hidesharing, 1000);
function hidesharing()
{
  $("span.ms-cui-ctl-largelabel:contains('Shared')").closest('a').hide();
  $("a[title='Share file or folder with other person or group']").hide();
  $("a[title='Share']").hide();
}
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not the answer I had hoped for, but thanks any way. Weird oversight on Microsofts part